# add module in a layout not globaly in the nuxt.config.js

Tags: nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

How can I add a module in a layout in nuxt and it works with the same layout and its pages and components?
I have tow layouts. One of them should work with "bootstrap-vue" with some component and another should work without that.
especially for vue-bootstrap. thx in advance

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: I would like to import '@nuxt/image' in the layout instead of nuxt.config.js

Comment: This is a module, not really meant to be imported locally AFAIK.

Comment: there is no other solution for this kind of modules? load locally?

Comment: For this one? I don't think so. I've asked on Github discussions tho: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/5648 Don't want to spread false information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution maybe it is useful for the others.
I added bootstrap-vue like this to my layout.
You can add more plugins if you want or the whole package.
some packages that I needed

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import { LayoutPlugin, NavbarPlugin,CardPlugin,BAlert } from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(LayoutPlugin)
Vue.use(NavbarPlugin)
Vue.use(CardPlugin)
```

for all bootstrap-vue you can do like this

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `Vue.use` will import it make it global again, especially since it's in your default layout. There is no real benefit here.

Comment: Yes. Of course, it makes it global. but in the build in hybrid mode it is useful. Isn't it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. No, it should be still exactly the same.